# regular expression to extract insert sql statement from a text file and to check for hardcoded parameters

Tags: regex

I have a bunch of sql statements updated by my team developers.
I intend to run a check before these statements are run against a db.
for example, check if a certain column is hardcoded instead of being fetched from the respective table (foreign key)

for example:

> INSERT INTO [Term1] ([CreatedBy]
>   ,[CreateUser]) values(1,'asdadad')

where 1 is hardcoded value.

Is there a regular expression that can extract all insert statements from the file so that they can be parse?

I tried with this expression http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=1750 but it didnot work

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run a multi-level regex on this. First parse the entire parameter string from the whole query, then parse each individual field from the paramter string that you previously got to get each one specifically ignoring all the other characters that may come up.